# How to copy unknown object?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, io, clone

I would like to know how it is possible to copy object in Java. But I mean copy without implementing clonable interface but copy already existing object with all contains other objects, for example:

```
JEditorPane editorOryginal = new JEditorPane();
editorOryginal.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {});
editorOryginal.setText("Hello World!");
// ...... other setter and other listeners etc ..    

JEditorPane editorCopy = editorOryginal  // now i only copy reference to editorOryginal

//but i would like to get copy of object:

JEditorPane editorCopy = editorOryginal.getCopyInstance();       
editorOryginal.destroy(); // in JEditorPane this method not exists but we assume existing this method
editorCopy.something(); // here i have my copy but oryginal has been destroyed
```

Comment: search for model/XxxEditorKit

Comment: but i need all not only editorKit, components, listeners etc ..

Comment: Take a look at [Java deep cloning](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/)

Comment: You will get the necessary explanation from this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#In_Java

Answer (score 0):

There is no general mechanism for this in Java. For a class to allow copying objects, it should implement a copying mechanism (for example Cloneable).

In principle, I suppose it would be possible to copy objects using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), picking one member at a time and building a copy, but it will be difficult to make it work. Note that it means you have to access private members too. And even if you succeed, there is no guarantee that it will work as you expect for classes that you don't control…

Consider this:

```
class A {
    int i;
}

class B {
    A a;
}

class C {
    B b;
}

void f(C c) {
    C c2 = c.getCopyInstance();

    // What is c2.b now?
}
```

Should c2.b be the same as c.b (i.e., c2 is a shallow copy) or should it be a new copy of c.b (deep copy)? In some cases, you would want a deep copy, but for shared resources (something representing the screen or the disk for example), you just want to assign the reference. There is no way to decide in general what is the right way to copy an object.

Comment: Note that there are existing libraries that already handle all of this, such as Apache BeanUtils.

Comment: For general objects? I would have assumed, for instance, that BeanUtils handle only beans. Anyway, I maintain that there is no method that will work as intended for all kinds of objects.